# SSRS error "Conversion Failed when Converting the nvarchar value to data type int"

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

I created the following to show the text when the corresponding value shows up

```
SELECT distinct 
case changeqtytype
    when 1 then 'Defect'
    when 2 then 'Loss'
    when 3 then 'Sell'
    when 4 then 'Adjust'
    when 5 then 'Bonus'
    when 6 then 'Buy'
END as ChangeQty_Type
FROM QtyHistoryDetails
```

When I execute the query, the correct values come out but when I run it in SSRS, I see the following error:

> Conversion Failed when Converting the nvarchar value '_____' to data
> type int
> ***Enter values between "xxxx' defined above.

How Do i get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

Presumably, `changqtytype` is a string.  So use string comparisons:

```
SELECT distinct 
    (case changeqtytype
         when '1' then 'Defect'
         when '2' then 'Loss'
         when '3' then 'Sell'
         when '4' then 'Adjust'
         when '5' then 'Bonus'
         when '6' then 'Buy'
     end) as ChangeQty_Type
from QtyHistoryDetails
```